# Simulating FlatList actions with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing some unit tests for a componente that renders a FlatList and I need to simulate some actions like scrollTo and scrollToEnd.

Anyone knows how can I reach this?

I'm using Jest and Enzyme for tests.

```
import React form "react";
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe("<FlatList/>", () => {
  const callback = jest.fn();

  it("how to simulate scroll?", () => {
    const list = mount(<FlatList onEndReach={callback}/>);

    //how to simulate scrool and reach the end of the list?

    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

Calling scrollToEnd() from instance of mounted object didn't work.

```
const flatList = wrapper.find(FlatList);
flatList.first().instance().scrollToEnd();
```

```
Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
```

In my simulation I want to call the callback function when Flatlist.scrollToEnd() is called.

Comment: are you testing `<FlatList />` itself or some own component that renders `<FlatList />`?

Comment: I'm testing a component that renders a Flatlist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you test your component not `FlatList` itself I believe you better think in somehow abstract way: instead of working on low-level thing like emulating scroll just call the props:

```
list.find(FlatList).prop('onEndReach')();
```

or with `simulate()` syntax sugar:

```
list.find(FlatList).simulate('endReach');
```

To me it's not only easier than simulating scrolling but also better maintainable.

Comment: I think it is not the most efficient aproach in my case, because onEndReach stop to work when FlatList is nested in another ScrowView type componente, and calling the function directly will not test this behavior.

Comment: I think unit testing just cannot cover everything. say(not sure if this applicable to react native) you may get button visible but unclickable by placing some absolute or relative positioned block above it. and there will be no way to cover that with unit test. or color text may be equal to background color so user would never read it. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
it('should scrollend call request', async () => {
  const {findByText, getByTestId} = render(component);
  const flatList = getByTestId('listsFlatList');
  

  const eventData = {
    nativeEvent: {
      contentOffset: {
        y: 500,
        x: 0,
      },
      contentSize: {
        // Dimensions of the scrollable content
        height: 500,
        width: 100,
      },
      layoutMeasurement: {
        // Dimensions of the device
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      },
    },
  };
  await waitFor(() => fireEvent.scroll(flatList, eventData));
  waitFor(() => {
    expect(findByText('something')).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```